# MAX(id) using SqlDataReader C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

How do I change this:

```
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT FormID FROM tbl_Form";
            using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int FormID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("FormID"));
                    MessageBox.Show(FormID.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

to get **MAX(FormID)** ?

My natural tendency is to throw a MAX around FormID but I'm getting an IndexOutOfRange exception.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you select the maximum id  you shouldn't use  a `SqlDataReader` - the query returns just one item, which by default is unnamed so your existing query breaks because it expects a result named "FormID"   - although you could have "fixed" your query by using `"SELECT MAX(FormID) as FormId FROM tbl_Form"`. Instead use [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(FormID) FROM tbl_Form";
int maxId = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Definitely the simplest solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used this style of database access, but I think you just need

```
select max(FormID) from tbl_Form
```

along with a call to ExecuteScalar